# why my adhoc profile will expire?

Tags: ios, distribution, profile, adhoc

I got notice from my Adhoc App at my Development device that, my adhoc profile will expire 2 days later.

But I want to use it as a Demo in next week.

Why that happens?

how to solve the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to the developer.apple.com and download the profile again and install. You should see a download link there. If you dont have access to the portal, ask the team admin/agent for the profiles.

Comment: Thanks ACB for your prompt reply. I just realized that my iOS Dev. Program will expire the same day as my adhoc profile. Is it because of this reason? And I do want to renew my iOS program, but according to Apple, they will have 3-5 days to process my renew process, but my iOS will due to expire tomorrow and they just notice me about that.

Comment: My concern is that, my Demo using the adhoc profile at the exhit. till this week end, and the Demo also gets prompts that the adhoc profile will epire tomorrow. even if I send Fax for renew now, and Apple will take 3-5 days to process, will my Demo stop to work at the break of my expiration and Apple's process of my renew? thanks!

Comment: I am sorry. If your iOS dev program is going to expire, I am not sure what to do in this case. Have never experienced that kind of situation.

Comment: thanks ACB any way. I got reply from Apple forum as follows: The profile will not let the app/demo run if it expires. Your app/demo will not run if your account expires. Even if you refreshed the profile now, it would not be valid past the current expiration date.
 
You should renew your account as soon as possible, then make a new profile when your account is extended/renewed. Contact Apple directly to be sure everything is done in time for your demo.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was afraid of. Sorry to hear that.

Comment: do you have the same problem with me?